# How to merge row cells in TanStack React Table v7 to v8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tanstack

I'm a newbie developer and I rely a lot on resources available on the web. I am developing this kind of table where it needed to be merged but I am using the react table TanStack latest version.

[image: The Table]

This is the table I want to create but based on surfing the web, I couldn't see one example or sample that could help me. Is this possible using this TanStack React Table package? or if you do know table package that can do it then you can also suggest it. Thank you for your time and understanding of my message. I may be writing it wrong but I hope my intention was delivered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find an example on grouped table on the latest version.
https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/grouping

Basic table
https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/basic
Did i answer your question ?

Comment: a good suggestion but based on my use case, it is not. Grouping does it job that aggregating the tables but the table should only just merge cells or exactly should display that table example using react table. Is it even possible using this package?

Comment: Is it similar to this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76998226/react-table-cell-merging-column-spanning?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C95.4096